# How to get JSON from http response

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

here is the issue,

I am trying to make a POST request using AFNetworking as below

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer]];

[manager POST:ZipPackersLoginURL parameters:@{@"Token" : @"myToken"} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    //success block
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    completionBool = TRUE;

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    //failure block
    completionBool = TRUE;

}];

return completionBool;
```

I am getting this response from the web service

```
UPDATE `users` SET FBID = 'xxx', email = 'xxx@hotmail.com',  FirstName = 'xxx',
MiddleName = NULL, LastName = 'xxx', FullName = 'xxx xxx', PictureUrl = 'https://xxx.xxx',
LocationID = xxx, LocationCity = 'xxx', LocationCountry = 'xxx', ProfileLink = 'xxx',
LastActive = NOW(), LastLoginIP = 'xxx'  WHERE FBID = 'xxx'{"status":200,"data":
{"AccessKey":"xxx","FBID":"xxx","Points":"0","FullName":"xxx xxx",
"FirstName":"xxx","PictureURL":"xxx","Country":"xxx","City":"xxx","CityID":"xxx",
"FriendsCount":0,"Friends":null}}
```

as you can see it starts with some sort of query and then it contains the JSON structure I want.

How to take only the JSON from the response above?

In postman, If i View the response in pretty mode it only shows the JSON, but in raw mode it shows the response above.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: How did you get this response? What kind of response is it really? Could you show some code?

Comment: I made a POST request to login url of the app I am making, Is there a way I could show you in private mode? I don't want t to be public

Comment: Just replace with ZzZ private things, like URLs, passwords, logins, etc. We essentially I think need the POST code, even if you say `NSDictionary *parameters = //Set private params` But I assume that the issue is about the success block code, and I don't understand what kind of response do you get really.

Comment: AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];  [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFCompoundResponseSerializer serializer]]; [manager POST:LoginURL parameters:@{@"Token" : @"dummytoken"} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) { NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  completionBool = TRUE; } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {  completionBool = TRUE;  }];  return completionBool;

Comment: Could you edit your question with your code, it's better (for people who encounters the same issue, or want to help you), since it's clearer and can be formatted. Could you show what you logged exactly?

Comment: sure! sorry I am a bit new here

Comment: `[manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];`, look at the value of `responseObject`?

Comment: If i do this, It will go to the fail and the error is 3840 (not a valid json) here is the detailed error  : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: looks as if it contains some sort of debug information. the web service should be fixed to respond with proper json.